# The best way to define a "between" macro in C

Tags: c, coding-style, macros

What's the best way to define a between macro, which is type generic (char,int,long)
which will return true if a number is between to other numbers inputted.
I'm tried to google it, but I didn't find anything.

Edit: The order of the two boundaries given shouldn't matter. so it can be more general.

Comment: The best way? *Don't do that*. :)

Comment: Don't blame C programmers; they tend to define macros for everything. They don't have `inline` functions.

Comment: Who needs inline functions? What's wrong with functions?

Comment: @Hossein: C has had inline functions since C99 (and before in many cases such as when using gcc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do something like:

```
#define BETWEEN(a, b, c)  (((a) >= (b)) && ((a) <= (c)))
```

you are going to have problem with the double evaluation of `a`. Think what would happens if you do that with a functions that has side effects...

you should instead do something like:

```
#define BETWEEN(a, b, c) ({ __typeof__ (a) __a = (a); ((__a) >= (b) && ((__a) <= (c)) })
```

(edited because the result should not depend of the order of b and c):

```
#define BETWEEN(a, b, c) \
           ({ __typeof__ (a) __a = (a);\
              __typeof__ (b) __b = (b);\
              __typeof__ (c) __c = (c);\
               (__a >= __b && __a <= __c)||\
               (__a >= __c && __a <= __b)})
```

Comment: Yes, but. Both `({})` and `__typeof__` are gcc extensions.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm working with IAR extensions of C. so this won't work for me, but it's nice

Comment: To make it compile in Clang, add a semicolon after `__a <= __b` in the last line. Built with: Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, don't use macros for things like this - use functions (possibly inline).

Secondly, if you *must* use macros, then what's wrong with e.g.

```
#define BETWEEN(x, x_min, x_max) ((x) > (x_min) && (x) < (x_max))
```

?

As per your subsequent edit, if you don't know the ordering of `x_min` and `x_max` then you could do this:

```
#define BETWEEN2(x, x0, x1) (BETWEEN((x), (x0), (x1)) || \
                             BETWEEN((x), (x1), (x0)))
```

The usual *caveats* about macros and side-effects etc apply.
Edit: removed space between macro & arguments for compilation

Comment: Especially the second version has the potential of doing RealBadStuff if the evaluation of `(x0)` or `(x1)` has side-effects (or is very expensive). The same goes for the evaluation of `(x)` in the first. I know that is what you mean by _'the usual caveats'_ but I'm not so sure it is clear to everyone reading this code.

Comment: This raises the following compilation error when using BETWEEN2:
Error[Pe020]: identifier "x" is undefined
Error[Pe020]: identifier "x_min" is undefined
Error[Pe020]: identifier "x_max" is undefined

Comment: @Mellowcandle: the two macros compile without without warnings for me - perhaps you have a typo - can you post your code ? Here's a working example: http://codepad.org/UFVAQA6j

Comment: @Mellowcandle: OK - I see now you fixed a problem with a stray space in the first macro - thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

If all types are the same, how about:

```
/* Check if 'a' is between 'b' and 'c') */
#define BETWEEN(a, b, c)  (((a) >= (b)) && ((a) <= (c)))
```

Note that if the types of `a`, `b` and `c` above are different, the implicit type conversions of C might make it wrong. Especially if you mix signed and unsigned numbers.

Comment: @Mellowcandle - well, of course not. If you wanted it to work both ways you'd need to add a logical OR (`||`) condition and repeat the check with b & c reversed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you will need 3 numbers, the upper limit, the lower limit and the number you're checking, so I would do it like this:

```
#define BETWEEN(up, low, n) ((n) <= (up) && (n) >= (low))
```

This assumes the between is inclusive of the upper and lower limits, otherwise:

```
#define BETWEEN(up, low, n) ((n) < (up) && (n) > (low))
```

Comment: Most reasonable coding guidelines for C require macros to be named with all uppercase letters, especially when they evaluate their arguments more than once.

Comment: Or for that matter, less than once: `low` is conditionally unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

+1: A not-so-trivial question, since it involves the problem of the evaluation of macro parameters. The naive solution would be

```
#define BETWEEN(x,l1,l2) (((x) >= (l1)) && ((x) <= (l2)))
```

but "x" is evaluated twice, so there may be problems if the expression has side effects. Let's try something smarter:

```
#define BETWEEN(x,l1,l2) (((unsigned long)((x)-(l1))) <= (l2))
```

Very very tricky and not so clean, but...

Comment: Almost, but it would have be `(x) - (l1) <= (l2) - (l1)` and you have that double evaluation there again. Plus you may not cast to `unsigned long`, because what if it was used like `BETWEEN(.05, 1e-4, 1e-3)`.

Comment: Nice thinking, but the math of (x) and (l1) may not integral: this breaks down badly some parameter is of pointer type

Comment: @sehe, I think one should leave out pointers, here. Comparing pointers is only well defined if you already know that they point into the same surrounding object. If you have such information via the context, you probably even wouldn't need a betweenness macro, anyhow.

Comment: @Jens: the use case would be that you know they're all pointers into the same array, but you don't know where. Much as you might have three integer indices into an array, and want to perform a "between" test on them. Knowing that they're all in the same array doesn't help tell you which one is in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define BETWEEN_MIN(a, b) ((a)<(b) ? (a) : (b))
#define BETWEEN_MAX(a, b) ((a)>(b) ? (a) : (b))

#define BETWEEN_REAL(val, lo, hi) (((lo) <= (val)) && ((val) <= (hi)))
#define BETWEEN(val, hi, lo) \
      BETWEEN_REAL((val), BETWEEN_MIN((hi), (lo)), BETWEEN_MAX((hi), (lo)))
```

See code running: http://ideone.com/Hb1vP

Comment: +1 only for getting me familiar with ideone.com, it's awesome.